# Super massive black hole mass estimation in literature

Tags: supermassive-black-hole, mass

What is the most accurate method for SMBH mass estimation? In the literature I could find 5 methods : (1) [Marconi & Hunt 2003](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003ApJ...589L..21M), (2) Hu 2008, (3) [Gultekin et al. 2009](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009ApJ...698..198G), (4) Graham 2007, (5) [McLure & Dunlop 2002](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002MNRAS.331..795M). Please tell me which is more accurate? Also, can you suggest other methods and concern references? Thank you.

Comment: Could you link the references?

Comment: Please, cold you summarize the methods that you found? Are you just talking about formulas, or actual methods? I do not think we have so many methods for SMBH mass estimation...

Comment: The three that have been linked so far look like calibrations of $M-\sigma$ or $M-L$ relations (or both). So I don't think any is fundamentally more accurate than any other. Not sure about the two that aren't linked (Hu and Graham). I echo @Py-ser's requests for a short explanation of each method...

Comment: Actually, in one of those papers `Gultekin +04` they mention `No other single parameter or combination of parameters of the host galaxy has been found to predict the BH mass with less scatter than stellar velocity dispersion`, from which my request for a better explanation, though suspecting the OP isn't following the thread anymore.